# Создание меню

Tags: html

Как создать меню типа `http://www.property.az`, оба меню.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере для создания меню используют таблицы. Имхо, это неправильно. Используйте html-списки и css-псевдокласс [hover](http://htmlbook.ru/css/hover). Примеры [тут](https://www.google.com.ua/search?site=&source=hp&q=html+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5&oq=html+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E+&gs_l=hp.3.3.0l10.1142.4468.0.7602.14.11.2.1.1.0.158.1294.2j9.11.0....0...1c.1.45.hp..1.13.1211.TdFJN1UkOyQ).

Comment: Не могли бы скинуть через jsffidle,у меня слова выходит за поля при увелечения экрана..

Comment: Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось. Другими словами, напишите сюда то, что вы сделали и что у вас не вышло.

Answer (score 0):

В простейшем виде это список с ссылками, стилизованный на ваше усмотрение:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/index.php">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="/menu.php">Меню</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contacts.php">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Мне наверху списка нужен еще блок внутри со словами,а эти слова выходят из блока,помогите

Comment: Уберите у блока фиксированную ширину, либо задайте её больше